# Unsure of the types for values

Tags: c

```
 void displayresults(double time, double range, double maxheight, double rovertime)
    {
      int hr;
      int t;
      int min;
      double sec;
      int roverhr;
      int rovert;
      int rovermin;
      double roversec;
      printf("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
      hr = time/3600;
      t = (time%3600);
      min = t/60;
      sec = t%60;
      printf("Flight time   : %d (hrs) %d (mins) %lf (seconds)\n", hr, min, sec);
      printf("\nFlight Range  : %.3lf\n", range);
      printf("Maximum Height: %.3lf\n", maxheight);
      printf("-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-\n");
      roverhr = rovertime/3600;
      rovert = rovertime%3600;
      rovermin = rovert/60;
      roversec = rovert%60;
      printf("Retrieval time   : %d (hrs) %d (mins) %lf (seconds)\n",roverhr, rovermin, roversec);
      return
    }
```

Im not sure why but im getting these errors from the compiler.
lab06.c: In function 'displayresults':
lab06.c:119: error: conflicting types for 't'
lab06.c:110: note: previous declaration of 't' was here
lab06.c:119: error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'double' and 'int')
lab06.c:121: error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'double' and 'int')
lab06.c:127: error: invalid operands to binary % (have 'double' and 'int')
lab06.c:132: error: expected expression before '}' token
lab06.c:132: warning: 'return' with a value, in function returning void

line 119 starts at t = time%3600

Comment: What is your compiler ? Do you compile with `-Werror` ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and study [ask]. It would be very helpful to create a [mcve], with sample input and desired output.

Answer (score 1):

`time` is declared as `double` (argument of `displayresults`), so result of expression `time/3600` is also of type `double`, but you are trying to store this result in `hr` (as well as in `t`) of `int` type.
Moreover taking remainder of the division (`%`) has no sense with arguments of `double` type - this is actually the error found by the compiler.

First of all check if you really get time as `double`, and in no, just change other part of program and signature of your function... perhaps it should be

```
  void displayresults(int time, double range, double maxheight, int rovertime)
```

If time is really comes as `double` you should make integer before use integer division (`/`) and remaining (`%`), e.g.:

```
  hr = int(time) / 3600;
  t = int(time) % 3600;
```

or better use the following operations with `double` type for all variables:

```
  double hr, t, min, sec;
  hr = trunc(time / 3600);
  t = fmod(time, 3600);
  min = trunc(t / 60);
  sec = fmod(t, 60);
  printf("%.0lf (hrs) %.0lf (mins) %lf (seconds)\n", hr, min, sec);
```

Specifier `%.0lf` in `printf` allows printing `double` as `int` (without fraction)

Comment: I think the `%` operator can only work with integers. So it's not that the result is double, but the modulo operator doesn't work with floating point numbers.

Comment: The line `hr = time/3600;` is warning free, even with `gcc -Wall`.

Comment: @VolAnd, the thing is, there is an execution output, and it shows as this,      Flight Time : 0 (hrs) 05 (minutes) 34.12 (seconds)                                                    Im not sure how to get the decimal places for the seconds, I know I have to use the long int, but Im not geting it that way either

Comment: Go on, giving sample input and comparing output to desired output is a very good idea. Inside the question, preferrably.

Comment: There are decimal places with your seconds output, two of them. What do you want different? Please provide desired output for sample input.

Comment: @skyblade1234 `trunc` and `fmod` functions from `<math.h>` will help you